# Creating a .jar file of a project that uses lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am using eclipse v.4.2.2 and I am trying to create an executable .jar file of my project.
I have tried simply using the export option, but when I do it shows an error because it cannot find openGL. I did check the box that says "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".
  What am I doing wrong or what am I not doing?

Comment: I would do a `jar -tf myjar.jar` to make sure the expected openGL libraries are there.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: You say you checked the box that says "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".  So I would make sure it did that.  Open the jar file that it created with any zip reader (winzip, 7-zip, whatever) and look in there to make sure the openGL class files are in there.  (the `jar -tf` is just a command-line version of that).

Comment: Does your openGL library need any native components?  (DLL's)

Comment: The files are there. How can I find out whether it needs native components?

Comment: OpenGL have native bindings (machine code interfacing Java to libraries) and those need special treatment.  Your easiest option for sharing with others may be Java WebStart (which Netbeans support directly).

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you could post, or maybe the exact error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) it's really simple and efficient.

.First export your lwjgl project as a regular jar using eclipse.

.Second use [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) and add all the necessary jar's.(Your game, and all the used libraries).

.Third add the needed natives.

.Fourth add the main class path which would be something like `example.main.MainClass`depending on your package hierarchy.

.Fifth create a fat jar.

.(Optional) Create an Windows .exe, a Linux .sh, or a Mac .app

I hope this helps.